# Ajax Update Panel Random Error 'PRM_MissingPanel'

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I use the Ajax Update Panel in Visual Studio to handle post backs for my search function on the site. (IE searching for a member) Will generate a gridview with the results. Every time I get the newest version from TFS, it throws this error:

> unhandled exception at line 1, column 132567 in http://localhost:58921/bundles/MsAjaxJs? JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get the property 'PRM_MissingPanel' of undefined or null reference

After it breaks, I can debug again and it won't break until I get a newer version.

I have done a lot of Googling and I can't find what PRM_MissingPanel is.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

MsAjaxBundle comes from ScriptManager, which was generated when I created my Web App:

```
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Comment: And wot is `MsAjaxJs` ?

Comment: It was something that was just there when I created my Web App in Visual Studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I was hiding a div with the update panel inside of it, and then changing the visible to true, but the Update Panel wasn't actually showing up.

Here is what I changed it to so that the update panels are always present as opposed to disappearing and reappearing:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div visible="false" id="Search" runat="server">
            <div style="overflow: hidden;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here: on my Login.aspx page suddenly it seems to happen out of nowhere for no apparent reason.

the solution proposed didn't apply to my case as my panel was not hidden, besides the same page used to work unmodified for one year.

It's a pretty simple page - I tried literally everything, no luck... until I added ID="SomeUnrelevantIDhere" to the asp:UpdatePanel, even though I don't use it in codebehind and even though it has been working for one year without an explicit id set there...

so my solution consisted in adding ID="something" to the updatepanel in the .ascx file.